# Technologies field is not cleared when adding multiple experiences

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When adding multiple experiences to my profile, the technologies field is always filled with the values that I selected in the previously added experience.

I think the technologies should be cleared when adding a new experience.

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add experience with some technologies
2. Save the new experience
3. Add another experience (without doing a page refresh) -> result is that technologies is filled with the previous selected items
4. Now when you save the experience, without changing the technologies, the technologies are not added to the experience

**Update:**
The same is true for Certifications

Comment: Can you tell me what OS/browser you are using? I just tested that in Windows 8.1 w/ Chrome and couldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Juice I´m running Win7 x64 with Chrome 33.0.1750.149. Other browsers i have not tried.

Comment: @Juice Even with FireFox 27.0.1 i can reproduce this

Comment: Ah ha! Looks like it only occurs during that page state. If you add an experience and refresh the page it doesn't happen. To duplicate I had to add an experience, save it, and then add another one. I'll get some one to look into it.

Comment: It's also a possibility it's by design from before I started. We shall see.

Comment: @Juice ok, but the technologies on educations, are cleared without doing a page refresh

Comment: @Juice nope, that's a bug. Fix coming.

Comment: I'll take a look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now fixed this so the Technologies list is now correctly blank, just like the rest of the form.